Rounding issue in Google Sheets
I have 3 cells in Google Sheets:

F2 is a formula that results in some number rounded to 2 decimal places. The outermost part of the formula is ROUND(x, 2).
H2 is a number inputted directly by the user.
I2 is the formula = F2-H2.

If (1) and (2) are rounded to 2 decimal places, why is (3) showing me a number with many decimal places?
In this screenshot, the values in F2 and H2 are the same and I've displayed them to many decimal places. I2 is somehow not 0 but 0.000...2328... why?


Floating point Representation
when (1)&(2) are rounded and displayed to 2 decimal places the floating point representation is not same. Thus leading to non-zero value for the equation I2 = F2-H2. -> 0.000...2328...
#try

I2 = ROUND(F2-H2,2)

